# Insert xml data to PostgreSQL using pg8000

Tags: xml, postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, pg8000

I have a S3 file containing XML data which I need to insert into a table in Aurora PostgreSQL database (PostgreSQL 11.9). To do so, I am trying to use AWS lambda. In the lambda function I read the data from S3 object and using pg8000 I am trying to insert the record in table. The insert sql is failing with

```
[ERROR] ProgrammingError: {'S': 'ERROR', 'V': 'ERROR', 'C': '42P18', 'M': 'could not determine data type of parameter $1', 'F': 'postgres.c', 'L': '1432', 'R': 'exec_parse_message'}
```

Example -

XML in S3 File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hotels>
   <hotel id="Taj">
      <name>Taj Campton Place</name>
      <location>San Francisco</location>
      <rating>4.5</rating>
      <rooms>
         <room id="100">
            <capacity>3</capacity>
            <comment>Phenomenal service</comment>
         </room>
      </rooms>
      <personnel>
         <person id="3030">
            <name>Pie Co</name>
            <salary currency="USD">80000</salary>
         </person>
      </personnel>
   </hotel>
</hotels>
```

Code to read the data from S3 file in lambda

```
    content_object = s3.Object(bucket, key)
    file_content = content_object.get()["Body"].read().decode("utf-8")
    #parsed_xml = ET.fromstring(file_content)
    print(file_content)
```

Code to insert the data

```
    conn = pg8000.connect(
        database='lab',
        user='master',
        password='xxxxx',
        host='lab.cluster.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com',
        port=8192,
        )
    
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(
        "INSERT INTO lambda_xml_test (data) values ('%s')", (file_content,)
        )
```

I have also tried

```
INSERT INTO lambda_xml_test (data) values ('%%')", (file_content,)
INSERT INTO lambda_xml_test (data) values (%s)", (file_content,)
```

Any suggestions on how can I insert the XML data to the table in PG?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the PostgreSQL server doesn't know that the type of the data you're sending is `xml`. See [the docs](https://github.com/tlocke/pg8000#could-not-determine-data-type-of-parameter) for more info. The solution is to put a [`CAST`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS) in the SQL to tell the server the type. For example:

```
cursor.execute(
        "INSERT INTO lambda_xml_test (data) values (CAST(%s as xml))",
        (file_content,)
)
```